# Using shared memory for communication of reader and writer threads

Tags: multithreading, memory, buffer, shared

I am supposed to synchronize two threads (which is accomplished using two semaphores for these two threads at this point). First thread is supposed to read a text file in chunks of 4 bytes (4 chars) of buffer and copy it to shared memory. The other is supposed to read from shared memory and and write it to another file. My program halts (because it cannot access to shared memory) after it has completed the process only for 16 chars. Can you help me fix his?

Note that im coding in a Mac thats why semaphores are a little different than default POSIX.

Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
//#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
//#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
//#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"


typedef sem_t Semaphore;

Semaphore * semList[2];

Semaphore *schedularSemaphore;


/*
* SEMAPHORE USAGE
*/
Semaphore *make_semaphore(int value){
    Semaphore *semaphore = (Semaphore *) malloc(sizeof(Semaphore));
    semaphore = sem_open("/semaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, value);
    sem_unlink("/semaphore");
    return semaphore;
}

void semaphore_wait(Semaphore *semaphore){
    sem_wait(semaphore);
}

void semaphore_signal(Semaphore *semaphore){
    sem_post(semaphore);
}
/*
* SEMAPHORE USAGE
*/

#define  NOT_READY  -1
#define  FILLED     0
#define  TAKEN      1

struct Memory {
     int  status;
     char  *data;
};

int fdIN, fdOUT;            /* Input and output file descriptors */

int BUF_SIZE = 4;   
ssize_t ret_in, ret_out;    /* Number of bytes returned by read() and write() */
char buffer[4];             /* Character buffer */


Semaphore * writerSem;
Semaphore * readerSem;

int readFileWriteToShMem(){
    key_t          ShmKEY;
    int            ShmID;
    struct Memory  *ShmPTR;



    int doRead = 1;
    while (doRead == 1) {


        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "HERE1" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
        ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x');
        ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Memory), IPC_CREAT | 0666);

        if (ShmID < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "*** shmget error (reader) ***\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "HERE2" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");



        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "HERE3" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
        semaphore_wait(readerSem);


        ShmPTR = (struct Memory *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);

        if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) {
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_RED "*** shmat error (reader) ***" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "HERE4" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

        if((ret_in = read (fdIN, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "HERE5" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has received a shared memory of 4 bytes..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has attached the shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

            ShmPTR->status = NOT_READY;
            ShmPTR->data = buffer;
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has filled  \"%s\" to shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n",
            ShmPTR->data);

            ShmPTR->status = FILLED;

            semaphore_signal(writerSem);

            while (ShmPTR->status != TAKEN){
                usleep(1);
            }


        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "HERE6" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            doRead = 0;
        }
    }



    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has detected the completion of its task..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    shmdt((void *) ShmPTR);
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has detached its shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    shmctl(ShmID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has removed its shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader exits...\n");
    exit(0);
}



int writeFileReadFromShMem(){
    key_t          ShmKEY;
    int            ShmID;
    struct Memory  *ShmPTR;



    int doWrite = 1;

    while (doWrite){

        ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x');
        ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Memory), 0666);
        if (ShmID < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "*** shmget error (writer) ***" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        semaphore_wait(writerSem);

        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer has received a shared memory of four bytes..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

        ShmPTR = (struct Memory *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);
        if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) {
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "*** shmat error (writer) ***" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer has attached the shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

        while (ShmPTR->status != FILLED)
        ;
        ret_out = write (fdOUT, &buffer, (ssize_t) ret_in);
        write(fdOUT, "\n", 1);
        if(ret_out != ret_in){
            ///Write error 
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_RED "write error" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            doWrite = 0;

        }

        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer found the data is ready..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer found \"%s\" in shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n",
            ShmPTR->data);

        ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer has informed Reader data have been taken..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

        semaphore_signal(readerSem);
    }

    shmdt((void *) ShmPTR);
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer has detached its shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer exits..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    exit(0);
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    fdIN = open("textin.txt", O_RDONLY, 0644);

    fdOUT = open("textout.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);


    if (fdIN == -1) {
        perror ("error while opening input file");
        return 2;
    }

    if(fdOUT == -1){
        perror ("error while opening output file");
        return 3;
    }

    pthread_t *readerThread, *writerThread;

    readerThread    = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(*readerThread));
    writerThread    = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(*writerThread));

    readerSem = make_semaphore(1);
    writerSem = make_semaphore(0);

    pthread_create(readerThread, NULL, (void*)readFileWriteToShMem, NULL);
    pthread_create(writerThread, NULL, (void*)writeFileReadFromShMem, NULL);


    pthread_join(*readerThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(*writerThread, NULL);

    semaphore_signal(readerSem);

    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final, working code. there is no need to initialize & access to shared memory on every iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
//#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
//#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
//#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

typedef sem_t Semaphore;

/*
* SEMAPHORE USAGE
*/
Semaphore *make_semaphore(int value){
    Semaphore *semaphore = (Semaphore *) malloc(sizeof(Semaphore));
    semaphore = sem_open("/semaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, value);
    sem_unlink("/semaphore");
    return semaphore;
}

void semaphore_wait(Semaphore *semaphore){
    sem_wait(semaphore);
}

void semaphore_signal(Semaphore *semaphore){
    sem_post(semaphore);
}
/*
* SEMAPHORE USAGE
*/

#define  NOT_READY  -1
#define  FILLED     0
#define  TAKEN      1

struct Memory {
     int  status;
     char  *data;
};

int fdIN, fdOUT;            /* Input and output file descriptors */
int BUF_SIZE = 4;   
ssize_t ret_in, ret_out;    /* Number of bytes returned by read() and write() */
char buffer[4];             /* Character buffer */

Semaphore * writerSem, *readerSem;

key_t          ShmKEY;
int            ShmID;
struct Memory  *ShmPTR;

int readFileWriteToShMem(){

    ShmKEY = ftok(".", 'x');
    ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Memory), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    ShmPTR = (struct Memory *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);

    int doRead = 1;
    while (doRead == 1) {

        if (ShmID < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "*** shmget error (reader) ***\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        semaphore_wait(readerSem);

        if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) {
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_RED "*** shmat error (reader) ***" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if((ret_in = read (fdIN, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){

            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has attached the shared memory and received 4 bytes..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

            ShmPTR->status = NOT_READY;
            ShmPTR->data = buffer;
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has filled  \"%s\" to shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n", ShmPTR->data);

            ShmPTR->status = FILLED;

            semaphore_signal(writerSem);

            while (ShmPTR->status != TAKEN){
                usleep(1);
                fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader is sleeping..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            }

        } else {
            doRead = 0;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has detected the completion of its task..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    shmdt((void *) ShmPTR);
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "eader has detected the completion of its task and detached its shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    shmctl(ShmID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Reader has removed its shared memory and now halts..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    exit(0);
}

int writeFileReadFromShMem(){

    int doWrite = 1;

    while (doWrite){

        if (ShmID < 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "*** shmget error (writer) ***" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        semaphore_wait(writerSem);

        if ((int) ShmPTR == -1) {
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "*** shmat error (writer) ***" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer has attached the shared memory and received 4 bytes..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

        while (ShmPTR->status != FILLED);

        ret_out = write (fdOUT, &buffer, (ssize_t) ret_in);
        write(fdOUT, "\n", 1);
        if(ret_out != ret_in){
            ///Write error 
            fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_RED "write error" ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
            doWrite = 0;

        }

        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer found \"%s\" in shared memory..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n",
            ShmPTR->data);

        ShmPTR->status = TAKEN;
        fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer has informed Reader data have been taken..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");

        semaphore_signal(readerSem);
    }

    shmdt((void *) ShmPTR);
    fprintf(stdout, ANSI_COLOR_GREEN "Writer has detached its shared memory and now halts..." ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    fdIN = open("textin.txt", O_RDONLY, 0644);
    fdOUT = open("textout.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);


    if (fdIN == -1) {
        perror ("error while opening input file");
        return 2;
    }

    if(fdOUT == -1){
        perror ("error while opening output file");
        return 3;
    }

    pthread_t *readerThread, *writerThread;

    readerThread    = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(*readerThread));
    writerThread    = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(*writerThread));

    readerSem = make_semaphore(1);
    writerSem = make_semaphore(0);

    pthread_create(readerThread, NULL, (void*)readFileWriteToShMem, NULL);
    pthread_create(writerThread, NULL, (void*)writeFileReadFromShMem, NULL);

    pthread_join(*readerThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(*writerThread, NULL);

    semaphore_signal(readerSem);

    return 1;
}
```